# sending bytes using serial ports to a zigbee

Tags: android, usbserial, zigbee

I am totally new to **Zigbee** and serial proting and I want to build a communication channel between a **Zigbee** and https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android through a USB serial port (send and receive bytes). I used the ***USB-serial-for-android*** project on Github https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android but it shows no way of sending bytes. So could anyone give me a way to successfully send bytes to the **Zigbee** module?
Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much when dealing with serial communication you need these 3 methods:

- open - open the port for communication
- read - read bytes from the serial interface
- write - write bytes to the serial interface

Additionally you may want methods for setting the baudrate, parity, stopbits etc. After a quick look on the github project, I see it exposes the above mentioned operations.
I suggest you use [pySerial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/) on your PC at first to accommodate yourself with sending and receiving data to/from your ZigBee device, and afterwards start developing on Android where things may get a little tricky. This Python module is simple to use and straight-forward.